# Matlab Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch error

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to perform row multiplication with two matrices: `A` and `B`.

A `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` error is thrown on the line `C(1,i) = A(i,:)*B;`.

Do I have a syntax error that is causing the dimensions on the left and right sides of the `=` sign to be unequal?

```
function C = rowproduct(A,B)

[n,m]=size(A);
[p,q]=size(B);

C=zeros(1,n);

if( m == p)
    for i=1:n
        C(1,i) = A(i,:)*B;
    end
else
    error('matrix dimension mismatch');
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `C(1,i) = A(i,:)*B;` with  `C(i,:) = A(i,:)*B;`

Comment: Did not resolve the issue.  I'm attempting to just fill a row vector (C) with the row multiplication values (C(1,i)).

Comment: strange...would you paste all data?. I tested with this sample `a=rand(2,3);b=rand(3,2);` (after replacing above) and it works OK.

Comment: My apologies - I took a stab at it again and it worked this time.  I had an error in my matrix initialization, and that was throwing the index error on certain matrices.